# Convention For Marketing Section

Tags: navigation, login, header

**Background:**

Part of a SaaS service is a web-management tool. The main part of the website, when you log in, contains a header with a lot of marketing-related links like pricing, benefit and competitors analysis, etc.

A lot of this stuff remains relevant for some SaaS users who are in the free tier but are already logged into the management tool. It is also beneficial for prospective clients that want to learn about the service.

On the other hand, paying customers gain no benefit from seeing it every time.

I imagine that this is frequent problem.

**Question:**

What is the convention? Does this marketing-level-navigation go away when a paying user logs into the system? Does it remain for the registered user that is in the free tier? Does it always stay up no matter what?

Answer (score 1):

You are right in your speculations. There is no benefits in bombarding your paying customers with the same marketing ads as your free-to-use users. They are two different personas that should be treated as such.

Your content should reflect the needs of your users. In your case, it seems there are two types of users (paying & non-paying). Each type of user has a specific set of needs that requires different marketing strategies depending on your end goal.